# Using HbaseTestingUtility with hbase-shaded-server and hbase-shaded-client

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, hbasetestingutility

I am trying to use `HBaseTestingUtility` 1.2 with `hbase-shaded-client` & `hbase-shaded-server`. It is throwing me the below exception. Can someone let me know how can I avoid this or `HbaseTestingUtility` does not work properly with shaded hbase client & server?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context$SContext cannot be cast to org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler$SContext
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.init(DefaultServlet.java:154)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:900)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeHttpServer.start(NameNodeHttpServer.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startHttpServer(NameNode.java:774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:838)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:817)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.createNameNode(MiniDFSCluster.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.createNameNodesAndSetConf(MiniDFSCluster.java:985)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.initMiniDFSCluster(MiniDFSCluster.java:814)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniDFSCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:987)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:862)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:806)
    at com.vnera.storage.metrics.HBaseTestTableFactory.<init>(HBaseTestTableFactory.java:25)
    at com.vnera.storage.metrics.HBaseTests.testCounterTimetamp(HBaseTests.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now `hbase-testing-util` does not work with `hbase-shaded-server`and `habse-shaded-client` because of the below open issue:-

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-15666